# Simplest way to awake multiple processes with a single broadcast?

Tags: c, linux

Context: this is a web/sqlite application. One process receives new data over TCP, and feed them to a SQLite database. Other processes (number is variable) are launched as required as clients connect and request updates over HTML5's server-side events interface (this might change to websocket in the future).

The idea is to force the client apps to block, and to find a way for the server to create a notification that will wakeup all awaiting clients.

Note that the clients aren't fork'ed from the server.

I'm hoping for a solution that:

- doesn't require clients to register themselves to the server
- allows the server to broadcast even if no client is listening - and doesn't create a huge pile of unprocessed notifications
- allows clients to detect that server isn't present
- allows clients to define a custom timeout (maximum wait time for an event)

Solutions checked:

- sqlite3_update_hook() - only works within a single process (damned, that would have been sleek)
- signals: I still have nightmares about the last time I used signals. Maybe signalfd would be better (server creates a folder, client create unique files, and server notifies all files in that folder)
- iNotify - didn't read enough on this one
- semaphores / locks / shared memory - can't think of a non-hacked way to use these. The server could update a shared memory area with the row ID of the line just inserted in the DB, but then what?

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious - but what? At this time, polling seems to be the best option!

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe signaling a `process group` would do. Man pages: [`man 7 signal`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=signal&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=Debian+5.0+lenny&format=html&locale=en), [`man 2 kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) and [`man 2 killpg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html) could be of some help in this case.

Comment: @chrk Thanks. I'll read these if I find no other option - as I wrote, signals means nightmare to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion can you try message queues? multiple clients can connect to the same queue and receive one broadcast message, each client can have its own message queue if it requires communication with the server.
Message queues are implemented by Linux OS and they are very reliable. I personally use message queues to pass messages from several clients to a central routing daemon, clients being responsible of processing and returning the altered data.

Comment: My (limited) understanding of message queues is that if multiple clients listen to the same message queue, only one of them will receive the broadcast. If each client has its own message queue, I guess it'd work, but it wouldn't be a broadcast anymore - the server would have to "know" each client. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: two ways of doing it. 1:using the functionality of msgrcv() see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgrcv.2.html you can leave the message on queue for other processes to read.

Comment: 2: make each client open a separate queue and use some logic to send the required message to each queue. But this would defeat some of your requirements. Now there is another way of doing this and this just hit me as i was typing... the http://enet.bespin.org/ enet library will do what you need. It is similar to message queues in the sense that it implements ordered message transmission in a reliable way. And that library has the broadcast functionality included. I used it as a replacement for message queues when i moved from one processing system to multiple ones.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Regarding #1: I still don't see how this would work. Someone still needs to removes the message from the queue at some point, otherwise everyone would be awaken forever. Who will that be? I don't think that when multiples listener are registered, the OS guarantee that it'll push the message to each of them, round-robin. So no-one will ever be able to tell that everyone saw the message, not even the sender.

Comment: Regarding #2: yes, I believe that either 2A (plain) or 2B (ENET) would work, but none of them looks "simple". At this time, I settled for polling, but I'm likely to revisit this once the remaining of the project is somewhat working. Thanks for the hints.